# Save state of GameScene through transitions

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I want to build an inventory for my SpriteKit game. For this I want to go to another SKScene File which represents my inventory when I press the pause button. My problem is that when I make a transition from my InventoryScene back to my GameScene, the GameScene loads completely new. This is the transition code from my GameScene class:

```
func loadInventory(){
    if !transitionInProgress{
        transitionInProgress = true
        if let scene = InventoryScene(fileNamed: "Inventory"){
            Globals.InventoryGlobals.levelBeforeSwitch = currentLevel
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            let transition = SKTransition.push(with: .down, duration: 0.5)
            self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
        }
    }
}
```

With this code I'll go to my InventoryScene.

Now in my InventoryScene I want to go back to my GameScene with this:

```
func loadLevel(level: String){
    if !transitionInProgress{
        transitionInProgress = true
        if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: level){
            scene.currentLevel = level
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            let transition = SKTransition.doorsOpenHorizontal(withDuration: 1)
            self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
        }
    }
}
```

The transitions are working but my problem is that the GameScene loads completely new, which is obviously because I instantiate a new GameScene. So when the player is in the middle of the level and then goes to the Inventory and back to the GameScene, the player is back at the beginning of the level. If I go from the Inventory back to the scene I want to be the GameScene as it was before (player position, enemy health, etc.)

Has anyone an idea how i can do this?

Comment: dont make it so that you leave your scene its more complicated/less efficient, import UIKit and add a UIView on top of your scene then build your inventory screen off of that

Comment: i can write up an example for you if you would like me too. give me an hour for testing and other things i will be back with an anwser

Comment: This would be great, thanks!

Comment: i need to know, is your inventory going to be interactable? will you be moving things around or editing text or whatever

Comment: I disagree with the advice that @E.Huckabee has given you. There is absolutely no need to implement a UIKIt UIView on top of your scene to do what you want to do. Why would you ever want to mix UIKIt and Spritekit if you didn't have to?

Comment: using UIKit will make it so that he will not have to transfer arrays of data between scenes which will make it way easier for him and besides almost every game i can think of (minecraft pe, mini dayz etc.) has an inventory menu on top of the scene

Comment: Yes, it's interactable. I want the player to select an item from the Inventory. The selected item is then the item which the player can use in the game. After it's selected, it's highlighted in the inventory. But there is no drag & drop or text editing.

Comment: I would not recommend what Huckabee is saying at all

Comment: ok KnightOfDragon how about you help him out. at least i am attempting to help him in a way i know how

Comment: @E.Huckabee you may be trying to help him, but the whole point of this site is to learn and share. So rather than getting defensive you should try to learn from this and maybe it'll help you out in the future as well.

Comment: i am using this opportunity to teach myself how to do it as well for my next game may have something similar to what he is trying to achieve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Retaining your scene is very simple,  all you need to do is retain the scene with a strong reference

In your `ViewController`, it is as simple as storing a variable

```
class ViewController : UIViewController
{
    var gameScene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene")
}
```

Now for as long as your view controller is alive, your scene will be alive.

To access it,  you just need to find a way to tell the MenuScene where your view controller is, then present the scene.

```
class ViewController : UIViewController
{
    var gameScene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene")
    lazy var skView : SKView = self.view as! SKView
    func gotoMenu()
    {
         let menu = MenuScene(fileNamed"MenuScene")
         menu.viewController = self
         skView.presentScene(menu)
    }
}

class MenuScene : SKScene
{
   var viewController : ViewController!
   func returnToGame()
   {
       view.presentScene(viewcontroller.gameScene)
   }
}
```

But, what if you don't want to use custom SKScene classes all the time, use a view controller, or would rather rely on components,  why isn't there a convenient way to go back to a scene.

Well my friend, there is, and it is where `userData` comes into play

```
class GameScene : SKScene
{
    func gotoMenu()
    {
         let menu = MenuScene(fileNamed:"MenuScene")
         menu.userData = menu.userData ?? ["":Any]()
         menu.userData["backToScene"] = self
         view.presentScene(menu)
    }
}

class MenuScene : SKScene
{
   func returnToGame()
   {
       guard let userData = userData, let scene = userData["backToScene"] as? SKScene
       view.presentScene(scene)
   }
}
```

Since we are retaining it in the user data,  we can now present the old scene anywhere we have access to the menu scene.

`userData` is also great in transferring inventory,  of course I would create a class to manage the inventory, and just pass the reference via `userData`

Now, to create a menu that overlays the current scene,  that is as simple as applying a new node onto your scene.

You can even use a separate SKS file to layout your menu, and overlay it:

```
class GameScene : SKScene
{
    let menu = MenuScene(fileNamed:"MenuScene")

    func overlayMenu()
    {
         scene.addChild(menu)  //You probably want to add an SKCameraNode, and add it to the camera instead
    }
    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) 
    {
        if menu.parent != nil
        {
            menu.update(currentTime:currentTime) //do this only when you need to have a constant update call,  be sure to include additional functionality like `didFinishUpdate` in the approprate functions when needed
        }
    }


}
```

Of course now would be a good time to develop what is called a `worldNode`, also may be referred to as `gameNode`

Essentially what this node is, is the node that holds all your game elements.
This allows you to add overlay nodes that can pause your game.

Your scene hierarchy would like like this:

SKScene
--worldNode
----all nodes that belong in the game
--menuNode
----all nodes that belong on the menu

Now at any time,  menu can set the worldNode's isPaused state to true, allowing the game to pause and still giving you the ability to interact with the menuNode

Comment: nice! i will still work on my method of adding an SKView to the scene and removing it likewise

Comment: I would not recommend blending UIKit and SpriteKit if you do not have to.  Apple claims that they play well together, but in practice, I have seen huge drops in performance.  It is nice to go from UIKit to SpriteKit, and vice versa via storyboarding,  but to have a UIKit overlay is a performance hitter.

Comment: the performance drops are based on what exactly what you are using the UIView on top for if Apple says that they work nicely together then they probably do Apple has no reason to lie

Comment: LOL Apple lies all the time

Comment: ok....maybe but i have used SpriteKit and UIKit in unison together and they have worked marvelously together for me

Comment: Another benefit to sticking with Spritekit is you only need to develop for 1 scene size.  There is no need to have to worry about constraints incorrectly scaling your graphics,  you just need to make sure you properly handle the clipping due to to aspect ratio differences.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I don't want to have an overlay, I want the inventory to be a different scene. So I tried your code with the userData and it works well!

Answer (score 4):

I do layover windows all the time in my Spritekit games, and it doesn't have to be as complicated as you are thinking. Here is how you can do it all in Spritekit without leaving the Scene.

Create a new class which is a subclass of SKSpriteNode for your InventoryDialog.

```
import SpriteKit

protocol InventoryDialogDelegate: class {
    func close()
}

class InventoryDialog: SKSpriteNode {

    private var closeButton: SKSpriteNode!
    weak var delegate: InventoryDialogDelegate?

    init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(texture: nil, color: .clear, size: size)

        name = "inventoryDialog"

        //do some background design work here   
        let background = SKSpriteNode(color: .white, size: self.size)
        background.zPosition = 1
        addChild(background) 

        closeButton = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "closeButton"))
        closeButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2 - closeButton.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height / 2 - closeButton.size.height / 2)
        closeButton.zPosition = 2
        addChild(closeButton)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        let touchLocation = touch!.location(in: self)
        if closeButton.contains(touchLocation) {
            close()
        }
    }

    func close() {
        self.delegate?.close()
    }
}
```

inside your GameScene file

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    var inventoryDialog: InventoryDialog!
    var openButton: SKSpriteNode!

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        openButton = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "openButton"))
        openButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2 - closeButton.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height / 2 - closeButton.size.height / 2)
        openButton.zPosition = 2
        addChild(openButton) 
    }

    func displayInventoryDialog() {
        backgroundBlocker = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background3")
        backgroundBlocker.size = self.size
        backgroundBlocker.zPosition = 4999
        addChild(backgroundBlocker)

        inventoryDialog = InventoryDialog(size: CGSize(width: 500, height: 800))
        inventoryDialog.delegate = self
        inventoryDialog.zPosition = 5000
        addChild(inventoryDialog)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        //pause any action that you don't want running while the dialog is open
        gameLayer.isPaused = true

        let touch = touches.first
        let touchLocation = touch!.location(in: self)
        if openButton.contains(touchLocation) {
            displayInventoryDialog()
        }
    }
}

//MARK: - InventoryDialogDelegate Methods

extension GameScene: InventoryDialogDelegate {

    func close() {
        //at this point you could update any GUI nesc. based on what happened in your dialog
        backgroundBlocker.removeFromParent()
        inventoryDialog?.removeFromParent()
        gameLayer.isPaused = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: this is exactly what i was trying to achieve! very nice job now this is here for any other new developers trying to make a game! this is why i love stackoverflow

Comment: glad it helped. I agree this is why I love Stackoverflow as well.

Answer (score 0):

here is exactly what you wanted.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
class InventoryManager: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 200))

        //here is where you set up anything you want to display inside the view
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

        let Button = UIButton()
        Button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 20)
        Button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        let TouchView = UIView()
        TouchView.frame = self.frame

        Button.center.x = TouchView.center.x
        Button.center.y = TouchView.center.y

        TouchView.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown

        self.addSubview(TouchView)
        //make sure you add any objects that you want to the TouchView and not to the self
        TouchView.addSubview(Button)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
var InventoryView = InventoryManager()

var Node = SKSpriteNode()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    //this keeps the view centered in the screen
    InventoryView.center.x = (self.view?.center.x)!
    InventoryView.center.y = (self.view?.center.y)!



    Node = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.blue, size: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))
    Node.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 3, y: self.frame.size.height / 3)

    self.addChild(Node)
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        if !(self.view?.frame.contains(location))! {
            InventoryView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        if Node.contains(location) && InventoryView.isDescendant(of: self.view!) {
            self.view?.addSubview(InventoryView)
        }

    }
}

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        // Called before each frame is rendered
    }
}
```

clicking the blue button adds it to the scene again and clicking anywhere else removes it from the scene

Comment: Thanks for the help!